# (Kotlin Android), Using XML-RPC, encoded images to BASE64 are sent for a long time

Tags: android, odoo, xml-rpc

I am making application that uses Apache XML-RPC
https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/client.html
to send/receive information. server uses XML-RPC 1.1 (Odoo) and using website you can attach files fast, but using XML-RPC, image encoded to base64 getting sent for 1 minute or more (original file size is 6mbs). I partially fixed issue by encoding image to jpeg --> 80%,which will be around 700kbs, there it takes 8 seconds.
I tried using emulated phone, real phone, still takes long time.
I also noticed that if I use threading, like

```
Array.ForEach{
     Global.launch{
          CODE FOR SENDING IMAGE
     }
},
```

all images done "uploading" at the same time, so if I sent 1 or 5 images, it doesn't matter, they all getting done at the same time.

my function for uploading looks like this: (create image)
[My function for adding new entries to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSDig.png)

[How I call my function in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s34Hq.png)

[it.encoded is this, image encoded to base64 format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpV6s.png)

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE, to make it easier to fix, I created new project with specific part that is at fault. https://github.com/heromanofe/xmlrpcODOOFIX
for this, I use odoo demo site ( https://demo3.odoo.com/web ) or ( https://demo.odoo.com/web )
the only problem is, database often is deleted, so if application crashes, go to demo3 site and find database by going into settings and on top right you will see database name then in main activity change db to that name.

--> to make it even easier to see result, use this page:
https://demo3.odoo.com/web#id=3&action=548&active_id=5&model=project.task&view_type=form&cids=1&menu_id=422.
thanks for help.